# What are some of the reasons for voltage spikes in voltage regulated DC circuits?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, decoupling-capacitor

Decoupling capacitors are often used to protect ICs against voltage spikes
even in circuits that contain voltage regulation of some sort (even something as simple as a zener shunt)

What causes voltage spikes to occur even in a voltage regulated dc circuit ?

Comment: It's more likely to be very short duration *dips* in voltage rather than 'spikes' which may suggest a brief increase in voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following may be the cause:

1. External inductive loads-Relays / inductive coils
   Which will generate EMI / RFI Which will travel thru’long 
   Cooection wires and if impedance of the connecting wires matches the level of spilke voltage
   Will be more and will be beyond suppression and may destroy the devices.
2. Provide Back EMF quenches for external load if any
3. For sensitive ic circuits grounded guard rings should be provided in the pcb itself

Answer (score 1):

The chips may consume current in pulses (think a clock or microcontroller running at 1 MHz).

When connecting such spikey current consumer ICs with long wires (on PCB) to voltage regulator, the stray inductance of these wires cause the voltage to drop momentarily at the chip during a current pulse. Which is why you need decoupling capacitors to keep the impedance low at the chip.

Comment: What do you mean by "Keep the impedance low at the chip", a fast discharge of the capacitor to compensate for the voltage drop ?

Comment: Yes. Because inductance of the wires will limit how fast the current will change to the required level, so that's why there are capacitors to provide local energy storage.

Comment: so the decoupling capacitors used with ICs are mainly  for balancing the drops rather than protection against spikes ?

Answer (score 1):

Given lots of fast spikes come into the voltage regulators, and the regulators have finite operating current and thus can precisely perform their servo-loop task up to some moderate frequency, the fast spikes come thru because of the low bandwidth of the servo-loop.

And the large onchip transistors have massive parasitic capacitances between input (raw DC) and output, thus the spikes just sail on through.